# Ionic 5 unable two upload 2 files in the same page, wrong function called

Tags: angular, ionic5

I have an Ionic 5 application where I need to upload 2 separate files on the same page. I have functions that handle this for both the phone and the browser. In this case it is the browser that is in error.

The two functions for the browser that handle this on mypage.page.html are as follows:

```
<div class="container">
      <h5 class="ion-padding-start">Doctor's Note:</h5>
      <div [hidden]="!editState">
        <div id="upload" [hidden]="!isphone">
           <ion-button color="primary" fill='clear' (click)="uploadDocNotePhone()" >Upload Phone</ion-button>
           <ion-icon name="document-outline" [class.red]="docURL === ''" [class.green]="docURL !== ''" ></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div id="upload" [hidden]="isphone">
            <ion-button color="primary" fill='clear'>
              <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" (change)="uploadDocNoteComputer($event)" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.pdf,.doc,.docx"/>
              <label for="file">Upload Computer</label>
              <ion-icon name="document-outline" [class.red]="docURL === ''" [class.green]="docURL !== ''"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>

    <div class="container">
      <h5 class="ion-padding-start">Vaccination Records:</h5>
      <div [hidden]="!editState">
        <div id="upload" [hidden]="!isphone">
           <ion-button color="primary" fill='clear' (click)="uploadVaccRecordPhone()">Upload Phone</ion-button>
           <ion-icon name="document-outline" [class.red]="vaccURL === ''" [class.green]="vaccURL !== ''"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div id="upload" [hidden]="isphone">
            <ion-button color="primary" fill='clear'>
              <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" (change)="uploadVaccRecordComputer($event)" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.pdf,.doc,.docx"/>
              <label for="file">Upload Computer</label>
              <ion-icon name="document-outline" [class.red]="vaccURL === ''" [class.green]="vaccURL !== ''"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

The Corresponding functions in mypage.page.ts are as follows:

```
async uploadVaccRecordComputer(event) {
    const randKidDocRefId = this.calcService.makeRandomId(15);
    this.loadingService.present();
    await this.browserImageService.uploadVaccinationRecords(event, randKidDocRefId, "application/pdf").then((uploadedurl: any) => {
            this.loadingService.dismiss();
            console.log('uploadedurl 1: ', uploadedurl);
            this.vaccURL = uploadedurl;
    });
    this.loadingService.dismiss();
  }


async uploadDocNoteComputer(event) {
    const randKidDocRefId = this.calcService.makeRandomId(15);
    this.loadingService.present();
    await this.browserImageService.uploadDoctorsNote(event, randKidDocRefId, "application/pdf").then((uploadedurl: any) => {
            this.loadingService.dismiss();
            this.docURL = uploadedurl;
    });

    this.loadingService.dismiss();
  }
```

The corresponding functions in my service are:

```
async uploadVaccinationRecords(event: any, kidVaccRefID: string, contentType: string) {
            // contentType should be like 'image/jpeg' or pdf or some other type to set metadata

            console.log("IN uploadVaccinationRecords kidVaccRefID !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", kidVaccRefID)
            
            const metadata = {
                  contentType: contentType
            };

            const imgRef = this.firestore.ref('/vaccinationrecords/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/kidvaccref/' + kidVaccRefID);

            // DELETES OLD RECORD IF FOUND
            await imgRef.getDownloadURL().then((foundURL) => {
                  console.log("URL FOUND");
                  const foundRef = this.firestore.refFromURL(foundURL);
                        return foundRef.delete().then(() => {
                              const exit: ExitMessage = {
                                    exit: 0,
                                    success: true
                              }
                              return exit;
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                              console.log("This is the error onURLFound", err);
                              const exit: ExitMessage = {
                                    exit: 1,
                                    success: false
                              }
                              return exit;
                        })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                  console.log("URL NOT FOUND ERROR", err);
            });
            
            const uploadTask = imgRef
                                    .put(event.target.files[0], metadata);

// also tried  const uploadTask = imgRef.put(event.target.files[1], metadata);
// but no luck
            
            let tempProgFlag = false;

            const complete = async() => {
                        // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
                              await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
            
                        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
                        tempProgFlag = true;
                        console.log('PROGRESS', tempProgFlag);
                        this.progFlag = tempProgFlag;
                        console.log('PROGRESS 2', this.progFlag);
                        console.log('downloadURL here', downloadURL);
            
                        return downloadURL;
                        });
                  };
            
            uploadTask.on(
                              firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
                              this.nextFunc(),
                              this.error(),
                              complete);
            
            await this.waitonProgress();

            this.vaccurl = await imgRef.getDownloadURL();

            console.log('File available at past this.imgurl', this.vaccurl);


            
            return this.vaccurl;
      
      }

async uploadDoctorsNote(event: any, kidDocRefId: string, contentType: string) {

            console.log("IN uploadDoctorsNote kidDocRefId !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", kidDocRefId)


            // contentType should be like 'image/jpeg' or pdf or some other type to set metadata
            const metadata = {
              contentType: contentType
            };
      
            const imgRef = this.firestore.ref('/doctorsnotes/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/kiddocref/' + kidDocRefId);

            // DELETES OLD RECORD IF FOUND
            await imgRef.getDownloadURL().then((foundURL) => {
                  console.log("URL FOUND");
                  const foundRef = this.firestore.refFromURL(foundURL);
                        return foundRef.delete().then(() => {
                              const exit: ExitMessage = {
                                    exit: 0,
                                    success: true
                              }
                              return exit;
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                              console.log("This is the error onURLFound", err);
                              const exit: ExitMessage = {
                                    exit: 1,
                                    success: false
                              }
                              return exit;
                        })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                  console.log("URL NOT FOUND ERROR", err);
            });
        
            const uploadTask = imgRef
                                .put(event.target.files[0], metadata);
        
            let tempProgFlag = false;
      
            const complete = async() => {
                    // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
                          await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
        
                        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
                        tempProgFlag = true;
                        console.log('PROGRESS', tempProgFlag);
                        this.progFlag = tempProgFlag;
                        console.log('PROGRESS 2', this.progFlag);
                        console.log('downloadURL here', downloadURL);

        
                        return downloadURL;
                      });
                  };
        
            uploadTask.on(
                          firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
                          this.nextFunc(),
                          this.error(),
                          complete);
        
            await this.waitonProgress();
      
            this.docurl = await imgRef.getDownloadURL();
      
            console.log('File available at past this.docurl', this.docurl);
      
      
            
            return this.docurl;
        
        }
```

The doctors note uploads just fine and looks to be working as intended. The problem happens when I try to upload the vaccination record, it calls uploadDocNoteComputer (verified this with a logging statement). I am thinking this has to do with the $event variable possibly being shared, but I am not sure how to disambiguate this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It works when I change the ids on the files to file1 and file2 respectively. The ids just have to be different:

```
<div class="container">
      <h5 class="ion-padding-start">Doctor's Note:</h5>
      <div [hidden]="!editState">
        <div id="upload" [hidden]="!isphone">
           <ion-button color="primary" fill='clear' (click)="uploadDocNotePhone()" >Upload Phone</ion-button>
           <ion-icon name="document-outline" [class.red]="docURL === ''" [class.green]="docURL !== ''" ></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div id="upload" [hidden]="isphone">
            <ion-button color="primary" fill='clear'>
              <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" class="inputfile" (change)="uploadDocNoteComputer($event)" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.pdf,.doc,.docx"/>
              <label for="file1">Upload Computer</label>
              <ion-icon name="document-outline" [class.red]="docURL === ''" [class.green]="docURL !== ''"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>


<div class="container">
      <h5 class="ion-padding-start">Vaccination Records:</h5>
      <div [hidden]="!editState">
        <div id="upload" [hidden]="!isphone">
           <ion-button color="primary" fill='clear' (click)="uploadVaccRecordPhone()">Upload Phone</ion-button>
           <ion-icon name="document-outline" [class.red]="vaccURL === ''" [class.green]="vaccURL !== ''"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div id="upload" [hidden]="isphone">
            <ion-button color="primary" fill='clear'>
              <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2" class="inputfile" (change)="uploadVaccRecordComputer($event)" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.pdf,.doc,.docx"/>
              <label for="file2">Upload Computer</label>
              <ion-icon name="document-outline" [class.red]="vaccURL === ''" [class.green]="vaccURL !== ''"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```